# Is my implementation of string comparison is right?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isEqual(const char *a,const char *b)
{
    int lengthA=strlen(a);
    int lengthB=strlen(b);
    if( lengthA != lengthB)
    {
        return false;
    }
    int intLength=sizeof(int);
    int *ptrA;
    int *ptrB;
    int i=0;
    for(;i<lengthA/intLength;i++)
    {
        ptrA=(int*)(a+(i*intLength));
        ptrB=(int*)(b+(i*intLength));
        if(( (*ptrA) ^ (*ptrB) ))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    i=lengthA-lengthA%intLength+1;
    for(;i<lengthA;i++)
    {
        if(a[i] != b[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<isEqual("asasa","asasa")<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My idea is not to compare char by char but insted typecast it to int(4 byte comparison) and do the xor operation to test whether they are equal or not.
My question is that if only comparison require(true,false) is it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour.  (You are dereferencing an pointer to `int` where the pointed-to object is not int.)

The code will almost certainly be slower than strcmp (which typically does something like this *iff* the pointers are suitably aligned - possibly with the loop unrolled a few times).

Answer (score 1):

That code is ugly and unlikely to be faster than the simpler loop, but I don't see any reason why it should not work correctly, on a platform where `int` has no alignment requirements. On those where it does, you're inviting interesting behavior...

For production code, this would fail review on several counts. Most importantly, too clever by half, and you would need to show that it beats `strcmp` on any measure. I honestly doubt it will.

Comment: You are right.I have not thought about alignment requirements.Its just i thought would be good implementation.

Comment: I think to remember `strcmp` is sometimes implemented in that way, I means, comparing `int`s instead `char`s.

Comment: My intention is not be smart.But i am sorry i just want to know the opinion.I am just learning.